# How to fix strange "Undefined offset"? (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have these codes below, it always return *undefined offset* error.

I get the data value using `dd` it has value in index 1.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Title 1"
  1 => "Content1"
  2 => "Subcontent1"
]
```

But when I run error returned:

> Undefined offset: 1

My codes

```
class BlogsImport implements ToModel
{
    use Importable;

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        // dd($row);
        return new Blogs([
            'title' => $row[0],
            'content' => $row[1],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `dd` will stop after the first `$row`. Have you just tried simply `dump`ing the data? You need to confirm that there is data in column B in your spreadsheet all the way along.

Comment: you could try catching (pun intended) the exception, then dump the row that gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code this way

```
class BlogsImport implements ToModel
{
    use Importable;

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Blogs([
            'title' => $row[0] ?? '', // or $row[0] ?? 'default_value' 
            'content' => $row[1] ?? '', // or $row[1] ?? 'default_value'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a better check, because my columns are not nullable.

Comment: @JuanCervantes that case you will use or if (!empty($row[0]) && empty($row[1]) { ...},
or ['title' = $row[0] ?? 'default_value', 'content' => $row[1] ?? 'default_value']

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by using `dump` instead of `dd`. It turns out that there are some empty cell.

*thanks to @JustCarty for the hint.*

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    if ($row[0]) {
        return new News([
            'title' => $row[0],
            'content' => $row[1],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem, but your solution is not perfect, and is prone to breaking again if there are empty cells in another column. Consider using @Davit solution instead. It makes use of the [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to use a value if the left side is null.

Comment: @JustCarty but columns are not nullable.

Comment: As @Davit said, do `empty($row[0]) ? 'default value' : $row[0]` instead